# Substitute strings based on a match between two df

Tags: r, dataframe, radix

I have two `data.frame`:

```
df1 <- data.frame(species = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "ab", "ab",
                               "ac", "ab", "aa", "ba", "bb"))

df2 <- data.frame(original.search = c("aa", "aa", "aa", "ab", "ab",
                               "ac", "ab", "aa", "ba", "bb"),
                  search.str = c("aa2", "aa2", "aa2", "ab2", "ab2",
                               "ac2", "ab2", "aa2", "ba2", "bb2"))
```

(Just for a reference, string values in each name vector are more like "Ocotea porosa", "Alchornea triplinervia" — I just used simple names to better exemplify)

What I'm trying to do is, for each match between `species` from `df1` and `original.search` from `df2`, substitute the value of `species` in `df1` by the `search.str` value in `df2`.

In the example, both `data.frame` are the same size and the columns are already matched, but my real `df1` has close to 100,000 rows and my `df2` are the unique values found in `df1$species`

How to proceed?

EDIT: If no matches exist between `species` and `original.search`, then I need to keep the value from `species` in the cell.

Comment: If there's no match you keep the species value?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, I'll edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option - create a named vector from the `unique` rows of 'df2', and use that to match and replace the 'species' column

```
df1$species <- with(unique(df2), setNames(search.str, 
          original.search))[df1$species]
```

---

Regarding the non matches cases, we may use `coalesce` after doing the same as above i.e. `deframe` (from `tibble` creates a named vector from the 'df2' uniqued, and then does the match and replace with original 'species' column and `coalesce` with `species` so that if there are any `NA`s in the replaced column for a row, it gets replaced with the corresponding 'species' value

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(species = coalesce(deframe(unique(df2))[species], species))
```

Comment: I edited with an additional information, but maybe your answer already solves my issue.

Comment: @hiperhiper try the update